# How to change the color of items by clicking on the button?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I have two loaded models and an array of dbId elements of these models. I need to change the color of the elements of the models by their dbId, which I already have in the array. I had implemented such a function, but now I have to change it so that it works only after the user clicks the color change button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly is holding you back here? Shouldn't you just change the colors by dbids and model in your click event handler of the button?:

```
<button onclick="viewer.setThemingColor(dbid,THREEVecrtor4Color,model,recursiveFlag)">Click me</button>
```